# How to implement threading timer and thread pool to process message every second on C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer, threadpool

I want to develop c# windows application which processed messages from "inbox" table every second then processing it without waiting result from each process. I have been reading about multithread in .net, but i'm still not have the best method to implement. what is the best method to execute those requirement ??

1. Do I have run threading timer then execute thread pool ?
2. Or I have only use threading timer ?

please give your opinion and example for the best method I should to implement.

Thank You

Comment: Does it have to be 'every second' with a reasonably high accuracy? How much 'lag' can your system tolerate? How long does it take to process a message?  What is 'inbox table' - is it DB table?

Answer (score 2):

There are two simple ways. Number **2** is simpler, but number **1** is more likely to be on time if you are doing lots of work on the UI thread. You could also try the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) library, which is much cooler.

1) The [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) will raise the ellapsed event on a threadpool thread by default, which might be appropriate, but you need to watch out for race conditions if you are using data that is modified by the thread pumping the message loop. If you need to push the data back onto the UI thread, you need to arrange it.

2) Use a timer running off of the message loop, like a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx), then use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) or the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) to perform the work on another thread. These have mechanisms to help you marshall the result back to the UI thread.

You also need to be careful that the timer doesn't elapse before you finish processing the work from the previous timer event.